# n_fft =2048 value is too small for length and can't extend empty axis 0 using modes other than 'constant' or 'empty

Tags: python, preprocessor, mfcc

*this is the error*

Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\spectrum.py", line 222
warnings.warn(
UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too small for input signal of length=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\datasetread.py", line 72, in 
save_mfcc(DATASET_PATH, JSON_PATH, num_segments=10)
File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\datasetread.py", line 54, in save_mfcc
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(signal[start_sample:finish_sample],sr=sr,n_fft=n_fft,n_mfcc=n_mfcc,hop_length=hop_length)
File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\librosa\feature\spectral.py", line 1852, in mfcc
S = power_to_db(melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr, **kwargs))
File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\librosa\feature\spectral.py", line 1996, in melspectrogram
S, n_fft = _spectrogram(
File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\spectrum.py", line 2512, in _spectrogram
stft(
File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\spectrum.py", line 228, in stft
y = np.pad(y, int(n_fft // 2), mode=pad_mode)
File "<**array_function** internals>", line 5, in pad
File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraypad.py", line 814, in pad
raise ValueError(
ValueError: can't extend empty axis 0 using modes other than 'constant' or 'empty'
*I am working on speech recognition system and by this code i want to extract features using MFCC*

```py
    DATASET_PATH = "F://MS//MS-4//LibriSpeech"
JSON_PATH = "data_10.json"
SAMPLE_RATE = 22050
TRACK_DURATION = 15  
SAMPLES_PER_TRACK = SAMPLE_RATE * TRACK_DURATION
def save_mfcc (dataset_path, json_path, n_mfcc=13, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512, num_segments=5):
   
    data = {
        "mapping": [ ],
        "mfcc": [ ],
        "labels": [ ]}

    num_samples_per_segment = int(SAMPLES_PER_TRACK / num_segments)
    expected_num_mfcc_vectors_per_segment = math.ceil(num_samples_per_segment / hop_length)
    for i, (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in enumerate(os.walk(dataset_path)):
        if dirpath is not dataset_path:

            dirpath_components = os.path.split(dirpath)
            semantic_label = dirpath_components[-1]
            data["mapping"].append(semantic_label)
            print("\nProcessing: {}".format(semantic_label))
            for f in filenames:
                    file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                signal, sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr = SAMPLE_RATE)
                for s in range(num_segments):
                    start_sample = num_samples_per_segment * s
                    finish_sample = start_sample + num_samples_per_segment
                    mfcc=librosa.feature.mfcc(signal[start_sample:finish_sample],sr=sr,n_fft=n_fft,n_mfcc=n_mfcc,hop_length=hop_length)
                    mfcc = mfcc.T
                    if len(mfcc) == expected_num_mfcc_vectors_per_segment:
                        data["mfcc"].append(mfcc.tolist())
                        data["labels"].append(i-1)
                        print("{}, segment:{}".format(file_path, s+1 ))
    with open(json_path, "w") as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp, indent=4)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    save_mfcc(DATASET_PATH, JSON_PATH, num_segments=10)
```

Comment: Is there any code or a question in there somewhere or just a stack trace dump?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see How to ask a good question.

Comment: you can look at this link for help
https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1194